# Will Re-Render occur if state is changed without using seState?

Tags: react-native, setstate, rerender

I am trying to change the state as follows,

```
this.state.page = 0
```

I am not using `setState` as I don't want Re-Render to be happened. But still Re-Rendering is occurring. As per my knowledge only setState causes Re-Render.

Please correct me if i am wrong.And also please let me know how to prevent Re-Render when state is changed.

Comment: Please update your question with your code so that others can see and help you better.

Comment: you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle

Comment: You shouldn't use state in that way. As mentioned above, you could use `this.setState({ page: 0 })`. Then integrate `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`, this function should return `false` if there's a change to your `page` state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a value to this.state.param will not re-render the screen. You'll need to use

> this.setState({param: val})

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you can assign value to the `state` is the `constructor`. In any other place you need to use `setState()`.

From the `react-native` doc: In general, you should initialize state in the constructor, and then call `setState` when you want to change it.

So you can't change it with assignment, you have to use `setState`.